# How can I connect my TI-84 Plus calculator with my laptop?

Tags: usb, calculator, texas-instruments

I want to connect my TI-84 Plus to my Ubuntu 11.04 laptop. I use the organelle cables to connect it. The program `tilp(2)` didn't work or at least it didn't show my TI-84 Plus; I've tried to run it in root and in the normal way.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The libticables2-2 library supplied with Ubuntu 11.04 (and as of this writing, 11.10 too) supports the SilverLink cables only. I've just uploaded a patch which adds support for the TI-84+ calculator which is available in [LP #747589](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libticables/+bug/747589).

#### Overview of the fix

- Update the udev rules to avoid having to run the program as root
- Adding yourself to the `tilp` group so you may use the device without running as root
- Specify the calculator type to `tilp`

Instructions for installing tilp and getting it to work with the TI-84+:

1. Install the `tilp` package and its dependencies like libticables2-2: `sudo apt-get install tilp`
2. Download [the patch](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/79510370/new-devices-and-fixed-sysfs-warning.patch):

   ```
   wget https://launchpadlibrarian.net/79510370/new-devices-and-fixed-sysfs-warning.patch
   ```
3. Apply the patch to the installed udev rules:

   ```
   sudo patch /lib/udev/rules.d/45-libticables.rules < new-devices-and-fixed-sysfs-warning.patch
   ```
4. Add yourself to the `tilp` group:

   ```
   sudo usermod -a -G tilp $USER
   ```
5. Re-login to apply the group settings
6. The TI-84+ uses an USB-A - USB-B connector which is called DirectLink. This should be detected automatically. Connect the calculator now to the computer. If you've previously had connected it already, disconnect and reconnect it.
7. Now make known to `tilp` that you're using a TI-84+ calculator by running:

   ```
   tilp --calc=ti84+ --cable=DirectLink
   ```

   This will set the `calc=TI84+` and `cable_model=DirectLink` in the `~/.tilp` configuration file. After running the above command, it's sufficient to run just `tilp` in the future (using the application menu or by running the command directly).

Comment: This works greats except that you must start with "tilp --calc-ti84 --cable=DirectLink" Marked and voted up and droping windows even more. Thank you

Comment: I found out that you indeed have to include `--cable=DirectLink` the first time. Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You likely need [wine](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wine1.3)[image: Install wine1.3] installed in order to use the ti-84 tools. Wine is a Windows compatibility layer that allows you to run certain Windows applications in Linux. According to the [Wine AppDB entry for the Graph Link software](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=9967) there may be some issues running the program (note that the results listed are a little old, so the program may work fine).

Comment: -1: op stated that tilp did not work.

Comment: @Broam: Ooops... I missed that. Good catch. My answer has been updated now.

Comment: @George Edison I have tried to use the ti link under wine but it does not mount. Under Tilp it also doesn't mount.

Comment: @Rens: It does not mount? Are you referring to the GraphLink software on the CD that came with your calculator? Do you mean that it doesn't install?

Comment: @George Edison no I'm referring to the calculator.

Comment: @Rens: What **exactly** are you expecting to happen and what happens instead?

Comment: @George I want to be able to backup my data and update my data. Tilp doesn't work and ti connect in wine refuse to connect the TI 84+ in windows it does work.

Comment: @George Now I have tried programs for the ti 83 but these crash in wine. I don't think it is possible to do what I want (if you have a Ti 83 or 89 it will work not with a 84+)

Comment: @Rens: The TI software does not work with the USB ports completely well for the Calculators.  I got a TI084+ Silver Edition and I couldn't get it to work in 9.04 or any other version.  The TI-89 is the same way - the software does not operate correctly in a Linux environment.  And you can't "mount" the calculator like a drive - it doesn't operate in that manner at all.  The software needs to create the link, and use itself, to transfer data back in forth - this functionality does not work in the Linux environment, even under Wine, Mono, or similar.

Comment: @Rens: I know someone with a Ti-84 SE - perhaps I can take a look at it later... we'll see.

Comment: @The Evil Phoenix are you saying that I have to log in on a windows pc (with the right software) or can it work in a Virtualbox?

Comment: @Rens I havent tested in a VBox'd setup of Windows.  Theoretically, it should work in a VBox'd Windows setup.  But it does, of course, work with any Windows system (and by the way, the connectivity software for TI calculators is **free**)

Comment: @The Evil Phoenix I will try a Vbox'd setup I hope I can say if it works tomorrow but it would be fine if I could use Linux to connect my TI84+

Comment: @Rens yeah, I hear ya.  Unfortunately for me, I have one too many systems, so there's at least one that has WinXp or greater on it (reserved for the programs that run evilly or not at all in Wine or Mono).

Comment: FYI: `tilp` works, but you've to make clear that you're using a TI84+ calculator. Running it with wine won't help since you need read+write permissions to the USB device.

Comment: @NathanOsman Image link died, please fix.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps TILP isn't working because of this bug?
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tilp/+bug/49251

Are you using a standard USB cable or the other connector?
Can you see the device by typeing "lsusb" in terminal?
Have you tried compiling a newer TILP?
Unfortunately last I checked wine emulation didn't support USB, but Virtualbox Windows may work.

Comment: @user778234 When I type lsusb in terminal I can see the device. (Bus 002 Device 010: ID 0451:e003 Texas Instruments, Inc.) I don't know how to compil tilp

Comment: Looks like the latest version and documentation is here: http://lpg.ticalc.org/prj_tilp/linux.html but there's a PPA that may be easier to install.

Comment: @user778234 This doesn't work because of the bug

Comment: Have you tried connecting the TI-84 with a standard usb, not a silverlink cable?

Comment: @user778234 I've got two cable both don't work.

Comment: Have you tried searching for a ppa on launchpad.net that installs & works?

Comment: @user778234 What I can see on launchpad.net is old ppa contain the old version which don't work. I belief there is no work done on that bug. If you could find a new ppa I will try it but I think it won't work.