# TILP 1.13 can't connect to TI-84 Plus Silver Edition

Tags: 12.04, usb, texas-instruments

I've already looked at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48787/how-can-i-connect-my-ti-84-plus-calculator-with-my-laptop), which helped, but not completely.

Here's the result of `lsusb`

```
Bus 003 Device 027: ID 0451:e008 Texas Instruments, Inc. TI-84 Plus Silver Calculator
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0451 Texas Instruments, Inc.
  idProduct          0xe008 TI-84 Plus Silver Calculator
  bcdDevice            1.10
  iManufacturer           1 Texas Instruments Incorporated
  iProduct                2 TI-84 Plus Silver Edition
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
OTG Descriptor:
  bLength                 3
  bDescriptorType         9
  bmAttributes         0x03
    SRP (Session Request Protocol)
    HNP (Host Negotiation Protocol)
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           35
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xc0
      Self Powered
    MaxPower                0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

#### Screen

[image: Calculator screen]

#### Variables

Starts importing and at the end displays:

```
(tilp:18440): tifiles-ERROR **: string passed in 'write_string8' is too long (>n chars).

Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

#### Applications

Does nothing

#### ID List

This one works okay as far as I can tell

#### Clock

Shows a popup and gives a console warning, but doesn't crash the program

> Msg: timeout occured while reading to the device.
>   Cause: check that link cable is plugged and/or the calculator is ready.
>   System: Resource temporarily unavailable (errno = 11)

```
(tilp:18547): ticables-WARNING **: usb_bulk_read (No error).
```

**EDIT:** I was able to successfully back up the calculator and dump the ROM with a [Silver Link cable](https://education.ti.com/en/us/products/computer_software/connectivity-software/silver-usb-cable-for-windows-mac/features/features-summary).

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Finally I find someone who has the same as me! Perhaps I should start a bounty?

Comment: @Arin feel free! If you don't mind though the winner should probably be based off of what works for you, since I've been having too many problems on my machine to test something like this